# Compare column A in two sheets of same excel workbook and copy matching row from sheet 1 to new sheet 3

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have one Excel file with two sheets as in picture.
What I want is to copy entire row from sheet 1 to new sheet 3 if item name in sheet 2 is present in item name of sheet 1.

Sheet1
[image]

Sheet2
[image]

Sheet 3 results wanted
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For **item name** column try this array formula, end with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`, here is my sample:
[image]

> =IFERROR(INDEX(F:F,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(A:A,$F$2:$F$5),ROW($2:$5),""),ROW(A1))),"")

For **Last** column, try this formula:
[image]

> =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($K2,$A$1:$C$5,2,FALSE),"")

For **Location** column, try this formula:
[image]

> =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($K2,$A$1:$C$5,3,FALSE),"")